# Sql Multiple Where Clauses on Same field

Tags: sql, where-clause

I have several queries in an MS Access database that I am rewriting in a SQL stored procedure. The queries have several filters applied to the same field.

```
select *
from DT.SM_T_OCDetails
where 
    (Rest1 <> 'S' Or Rest1 Is Null)
    and (Rest2 <> 'S' Or Rest2 Is Null) 
    and (Rest3 <> 'S' Or Rest3 Is Null)
    and (Rest4 <> 'S' Or Rest4 Is Null)
```

Is there a better way to write the

```
(Rest1 <> 'S' Or Rest1 Is Null)
```

part of the queries?  I looked at coalesce for it but unless I am doing it wrong, I don't think that works.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using coalesce:

```
coalesce(Rest1,'NOT-S') <> 'S'
```

Though I actually think your original is clearer.

Comment: Thanks, i just didn't know if there was an easier way to do it.